# Conflict in return type from base class with derived class using auto

Tags: c++, c++14

I have the following code:

```
struct A{};

struct Base {
    virtual A& internal() = 0;
};

struct Derives : public Base {    
    auto& internal() override { // <-- conflicting return type
        return internal_;
    }

private:
    A internal_;
};

int main() {
    Derives d;
    auto& internal = d.internal();
}
```

This fails to compile (tested on coliru - with gcc) with a conflicting return type - my question is why can't the compiler deduce that both `internal_` (and therefore the return type) is `A`? Is the type deduced for `auto` in a different stage of compilation for example than the one which checks the virtual overrides? Of course this compiles if you replace `auto` with the correct type - but that is besides the point.

(Here is the clang error, gcc is somewhat similar)

> main.cpp:8:11: error: return type of virtual function 'internal' is
>   not covariant with the return type of the function it overrides ('auto
>   &' is not derived from 'A &')
>
> ```
> auto& internal() override { // <-- conflicting return type
> ~~~~~ ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:4:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
>
> ```
> virtual A& internal() = 0;
>         ~~ ^
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.

Comment: Wondering why are you mixing runtime polymorphism (virtual function) with classy compiler time class-design (templates) ?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios, I looked at that question, but I don't believe it is (though I could be wrong..)

Comment: In Visual Studio I get: "error C3542: `Derives::internal`: a virtual member function shall not have a return type that contains `auto`"

Comment: @JonathanMee, don't have access to VS, so can't test with that... I guess it would be useful for gcc/clang to fix the error, but hey-ho..

Comment: @Nim The Visual C++ compiler did seem to provide more precise error information this time. Though if you [try to look up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2ha0b0w.aspx) C3542 you won't find anything :/ Incidentally you can use Visual Studio 2015's web compiler here: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: @Nim Your code wouldn't work even if `internal()` wasn't virtual. There is nothing to fix.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper, I don't get what you mean (if you replace `auto` with the real type) the above code should compile..

Comment: @sleeptightpupper Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [[dcl.spec.auto]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#14):

> A function declared with a return type that uses a placeholder type shall not be virtual ([class.virtual]).

`internal()` is a virtual function, so you can't use `auto`.

The [original proposal](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3638.html) indicates the reasoning for this:

> It would be possible to allow return type deduction for virtual functions, but that would complicate both override checking and vtable layout, so it seems preferable to prohibit this.